# Cake php acts differently on my local machine and on server

Tags: cakephp

I'm not sure why nobody has asked this question but I'm getting weird problems with CakePHP. 
Okay so I am new to CakePHP and I was doing my first project on it. I made lots of mistakes and all those mistakes were bypassed by CakePHP on my local machine. Even some serious errors were bypassed. And then when I uploaded those to my server, all those errors start showing up.

The mistakes I made which were bypassed on my local machines.

1. I used `$this->html->css()` instead of `$this->Html->css()` on one of my view file. And the view rendered correctly. But on server it gave me error "htmlHelper Could not be found"
2. I used 
   `public $components = array('Auth' => array('authorize' => array('controller')));`
   instead of 
   `public $components = array('Auth' => array('authorize' => array('Controller')));` On server it gave "Authorization Adapter 'controller' was not found" error.
3. And the most severe one was that I used
   `'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'checkVerify', 'action' => 'home')` instead of
   `loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'checkVerify')` and it worked perfectly without throwing any error.

But after uploading to server, they all started complaining.

Now, I'm using the same version of CakePHP on both my local machine and server. Also I've set
`Configure::write('debug', 1);` to core.php file on both my server and local machine CakePHP. They why cake php on my local machine doesn't throw errors and automatically correct error based on assumptions? How to turn off those automatic assumptions by cakephp.

Comment: Please update your question with the version of PHP, CakePHP etc. that you are using. Also make sure that what you are using locally ist the same as it is on the server. Otherwise, state so explicitly.

Comment: Unless your PHP/Web Server settings are exactly the same between your local machine and your server, it's likely that the difference in your server configuration is the source of your problem, not CakePHP itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conventions

Issue 1+2 is because you're not following [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) and you are developing in windows but deploy in linux. You don't say that but I can safely assume it from the results.

When in a view you write `$this->html->css()` cake will infer that you want to access method `css()` from a helper class `html` that lives in `htmlHelper.php`.

According to conventions though, classes ought to be capitalized so the file your class should live in should be `HtmlHelper.php`.

Cake doesn't want to create unnecessary overhead by making the file name proper each time (it is safe to assume you'd write good code according to what it expects), so it will request `htmlHelper.php` from the system. On your disk there is only `HtmlHelper.php`.

For windows, being case insensitive in the file system, it doesn't matter even if that file would be saved as `HtMLheLPer.pHP`, it will find it and return it.

In unix though, `H` is not the same thing as `h` so the file won't be found and cake will complain.

Same thing goes about `controller` vs `Controller`.

For the 3rd issue, I doubt it would ever work unless you actually had a `checkVerify` controller (again your naming here is wrong). I would take it as more probable that this code wasn't ever reached (perhaps because of wrong nesting in the array or key naming issues) and you had something else to show up that made you think it was.

### Conclusion

You should be developing (or at least test) on the same system like the one you will deploy. Even different PHP, apache or mysql versions might produce different results and that is not the problem of the framework.

Also, never use `debug` > 0 in production, it makes everything very slow and exposes sensitive information to everyone.